# How Can I Add A sleep or delay to this code?

Tags: javascript, facebook, performance, delay

I use this to add friends on facebook. How can i slow this code down so that it will only run once per set time period?

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('_3-8_ img sp_zYKR9BP4QJasx_27b6db');
for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) {
    sleep(2000);
    inputs[i].click();
}
```

Comment: This is the full code    javascript:var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('_3-8_ img sp_zYKR9BP4QJa sx_27b6db'); for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) {  inputs[i].click(); }

Comment: _“I use this to add friends on facebook”_ – so you are basically not choosing specific people to ask them to be friends, but just _spam_ whole lists of people displayed somewhere on the site with friend requests – _why_? Facebook will block you from sending friend requests after you send a certain amount of requests in this abusive manner anyway …

Answer (score 0):

This may not work because the class names look like they are dynamically generated.

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('3-8 img sp_zYKR9BP4QJa sx_27b6db'); 
    for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) { inputs[i].click(); }
}, 15000 );
```

Comment: This is delaying the program but i dont think it is delaying the part i want to be delayed. What i want to delay is the parameters after the for loop.I want to add a delay before inputs[i].click(); is performed.